# coffeescript jQuery - how to refactor this (noob) approach?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, refactoring, switch-statement

after starting to learn some coding I did this (very ugly, non DRY) star rating switch with bootstrap in a rails4 app. I already did the codeschoool coffeescript tutorial, but it seems ruby is a little easier to learn for me.

If someone would help with a little hint on how a "pro" would write this function?
Thank you so much.

```
@starSwitch =  ->
    label_1 = $("label#1")
    label_2 = $("label#2")
    label_3 = $("label#3")
    label_4 = $("label#4")
    label_5 = $("label#5")

    label_1.click ->
            label_1.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_2.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
            label_3.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
            label_4.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
            label_5.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")

    label_2.click ->
            label_1.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_2.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_3.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
            label_4.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
            label_5.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")

    label_3.click ->
            label_1.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_2.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_3.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_4.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
            label_5.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")

    label_4.click ->
            label_1.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_2.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_3.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_4.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_5.children("i").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")

    label_5.click ->
            label_1.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_2.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_3.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_4.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
            label_5.children("i").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")

$ -> starSwitch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
@starSwitch =  ->
  $("label").click ->
    $("label").addClass("icon-star colorfull").removeClass("icon-star-empty")
    $(this).nextAll("label").addClass("icon-star-empty").removeClass("icon-star colorfull")
```

If you have other labels on the page then add a class to your star labels (for example `stars`), and then change the code to `$("label.stars").click` and `nextAll("label.stars")`.

Comment: excellent! Thank you! I have learned much more from you answer than just how DRY this function could be! because I use font awesome: $("label.rating").children("i").removeClass("icon-star-empty").addClass("icon-star colorfull")